# Assigning DocIds in inverted index, mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

How to assign docIds while creating inverted index using map reduce? The way I achieved this on single machine is to have a global counter. I am not able to come up with similar solution with map-reduce framework. Zookeeper could be possible solution but can we do it with out that.

Comment: Is it similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737750/how-to-handle-id-generation-on-a-hadoop-cluster/11748679#11748679

Comment: thanks it will help ... just to give more context, i m trying to do url reordering for better compression of doc-ids list (inverted list) used in Information Retrieval system. I need some temporary doc ids to start my TSP and solution suggested should work.