# assigning IDs to hadoop/PIG output data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I m working on PIG script which performs heavy duty data processing on raw transactions and come up with various transaction patterns.

Say one of pattern is - find all accounts who received cross border transactions in a day (with total transaction and amount of transactions).

My expected output should be two data files
1) Rollup data - like account A1 received 50 transactions from country AU.
2) Raw transactions - all above 50 transactions for A1.

My PIG script is currently creating output data source in following format

Account  Country     TotalTxns     RawTransactions

A1       AU      50   [(Txn1), (Txn2), (Txn3)....(Txn50)]

A2       JP      30   [(Txn1), (Txn2)....(Txn30)]

Now question here is, when I get this data out of Hadoop system (to some DB) I want to establish link between my rollup record (A1, AU, 50) with all 50 raw transactions (like ID 1 for rollup record used as foreign key for all 50 associated Txns).

I understand Hadoop being distributed should not be used for assigning IDs, but are there any options where i can assign non-unique Ids (no need to be sequential) or some other way to link this data?

**EDIT** (after using Enumerate from DataFu)
here is the PIG script

```
register /UDF/datafu-0.0.8.jar
define Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');
data_txn = LOAD './txndata' USING PigStorage(',') AS (txnid:int, sndr_acct:int,sndr_cntry:chararray, rcvr_acct:int, rcvr_cntry:chararray);
data_txn1 = GROUP data_txn ALL;
data_txn2 = FOREACH data_txn1 GENERATE flatten(Enumerate(data_txn));
dump data_txn2;
```

after running this, I am getting

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate.enumerateBag(Enumerate.java:89)
    at datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate.accumulate(Enumerate.java:104)
....

Comment: If UUID is not an option, your DB schema uses numbers as IDs, you could write a UDF which does something described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737750/how-to-handle-id-generation-on-a-hadoop-cluster/11748679#11748679 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often assign random ids in Hadoop jobs. You just need to ensure you generate ids which contain a sufficient number of random bits to ensure the probability of collisions is sufficiently small (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

As a rule of thumb I use 3*log(n) random bits where n = # of ids that need to be generated.

In many cases Java's UUID.randomUUID() will be sufficient.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: Finally after trying various options, I created UDF using Java UUID and it worked for me - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is unique in your rows? It appears that account ID and country code are what you have grouped by in your Pig script, so why not make a composite key with those?  Something like

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(account, '-'), country)
```

Of course, you could write a UDF to make this more elegant.  If you need a numeric ID, try writing a UDF which will create the string as above, and then call its `hashCode()` method.  This will not guarantee uniqueness of course, but you said that was all right.  You can always construct your own method of translating a string to an integer that is unique.

But that said, why do you need a single ID key?  If you want to join the fields of two tables later, you can join on more than one field at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot assume Account+Country is unique (may be in future I can add other scenarios where I can get different rollups for same Account+Country combination and because of same reason I cannot join table on Account+Country with raw transactions), I am trying DataFu library suggested below by alexeipab.

Answer (score 0):

In case when your IDs are numbers and you can not use UUID or other string based IDs. 
There is a DataFu library of UDFs by LinkedIn ([DataFu](https://github.com/apache/incubator-datafu)) with a very useful UDF [Enumerate](https://github.com/apache/incubator-datafu/blob/master/datafu-pig/src/main/java/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.java). So what you can do is to group all records into a bag and pass the bag to the Enumerate. Here is the code from top of my head:

```
register jar with UDF with Enumerate UDF
inpt = load '....' ....;
allGrp = group inpt all;
withIds = foreach allGrp generate flatten(Enumerate(inpt));
```

Comment: Thanks alexeipab, I am trying this for my use case. Will let you know in sometime.

Comment: @alexepiab - Not sure but I am getting NullPointerException on my PIG script, added my actual PIG script above in question

Comment: this enumerate udf is bugged. the i and count variable are not initialized, causing the nullpointer exception. I ended up using my own slightly modified version: https://github.com/Data2Semantics/d2s4pig

Answer (score 0):

DataFu had a bug in Enumerate which was fixed in 0.0.9, so use 0.0.9 or later.