# how to share HashMap between Mappers in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hashmap

Can I share **HashMap** with different **Mapper** with same Values like **static** variable? I am running job in hadoop cluster, And I am trying to share variable values between all mappers which are running on different datanodes.

INPUT ==> FileID FilePath

InputFormat => KeyValueTextInputFormat

```
public class Demo {

    static int termID=0;

    public static class DemoMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {


        static HashMap<String, Integer> termMapping = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


        @Override
        protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(value));

                String line;
                String currentTerm;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        currentTerm = tokenizer.nextToken();
                        if (!termMap.containsKey(currentTerm)) {
                            if (!termMapping.containsKey(currentTerm)) {
                                termMapping.put(currentTerm, termID++);
                            }
                            termMap.put(currentTerm, 1);
                        } else {
                            termMap.put(currentTerm, termMap.get(currentTerm) + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I know you can broadcast a map in Spark between tasks. Never tried it with MapReduce

Comment: Thx, but i don't want to use Spark

Comment: Okay, then show your MapReduce code that you've tried to add a Map to. What errors did you get?

Comment: not any error but that cant share values and each mapper has own hashmap

Comment: Can you please show your code. What's your inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Not sure how we can help you if you don't have a [mcve] of the problem. I understand your question, but it might be an XY Problem. Please [edit] accordingly

Comment: this my code and my input is FIleID and FilePath With keyvalueinputformat

Comment: No, you can't share a hashmap between mappers. If you want to share data you would need to have a central store, ie Accumulo, Redis etc and read/write to them from the mappers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need to share anything.

All you are doing here is a variety of simple *word count* (of paths).

Just output `(currentTerm, 1)` and let the reducer handle the appropriate aggregation. You can also toss in a Combiner for improved performance.

You don't need to worry about duplicates - just look back over the WordCount example.

Also, I think you types should instead be `extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>` if you are reading a file and outputing `(String, int)` data

There is also a `MapWritable` class, but that seems like overkill

Comment: Assume that I have 4 input splits in which contain 10 file path, 4 mapper will be execute. **I want Generate Unique ID for each Word** **not WordCount** that's why need some counter for each mapper in which each unique words

Comment: Okay, then as explained here. You can use the Reducer's `setup` method to initialize a counter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737750/how-to-handle-id-generation-on-a-hadoop-cluster

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your filepaths look like, but `new FileReader(value)` will need to be reading from a networked file path, not local disk.